# How to look in part of array, for first element of specific value

Tags: c++

So I'm learning c++ and I have this assignment, which I have almost finished, but I have gotten stuck in an -important- detail:

So the assignment is a code that lets people book a plane ticket. I have to use a 10-element array (as the plane will have 10 seats) -the first five elements refer to first class, and the othr five to economy; array elements that are 0 represent an empty seat, and elements that are 1 represent booked ones.
(so plane[0]=1 means that seat number 1 is booked and it's in first class, and plane[8]=0 means that seat number 9 is free and it's in economy)

If customers want a first class plane ticket they press 1, if they want economy they press 2. If all seats are booked in a category, they should be given the choice to book a ticket in the other one. In any case, when they book a ticket, they should be notified that they booked a ticket, in which category it is, and the seat number. If there are no seats available at all, they should get a notification that "The next plane leaves in 3 hours".

I have done the code, but I have this problem: it works fine if the original array has all elements equal to zero. But as soon as even one element is equal to 1, I get the notification that all seats are booked in said category.

I believe my mistake lies in the beginning of my 'for' loops, but I can not exactly put my finger on it (since I am very new to this). 
The goal of my 'for' loops was to look in 5 specific array elements at a time, and as soon as there is one that is equal to 0, stop, replace the value with 1 and print the ticket & exit the programme.

So this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int linearSearch(const int[], int, int);

int main() {
  const int arraySize = 10;
  int plane[arraySize] = {0};
  int seat, i;
  string answer;
  int check = 1;
  int level = 5;

  int element = linearSearch(plane, check, level);

  cout << "Please press 1 for first class and 2 for economy." << endl;
  cin >> seat;

  switch (seat) {
    case 1: {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int element = linearSearch(plane, check, level);
        if (element == -1) {
          plane[i] = 1;
          cout << "You have booked a seat at first class, and you are seated "
                  "at seat number "
               << plane[i] << endl;
          break;
        } else
          cout << "There are no seats available in first class. Would you like "
                  "a seat at economy class?/n(Type 'yes' to continue and 'no' "
                  "to exit)"
               << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == "yes") {
          for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            int element = linearSearch(plane, check, level);
            if (element == -1) {
              plane[i] = 1;
              cout << "You have booked a seat at economy class, and you are "
                      "seated at seat number "
                   << plane[i] << endl;
              break;
            } else
              cout << "There are no seats available. The next flight leaves in "
                      "3 hours."
                   << endl;
            break;
          }
        } else
          cout << "There are no seats available. The next flight leaves in 3 "
                  "hours."
               << endl;
        break;

        break;
      }
      break;
    }

    case 2: {
      for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        int element = linearSearch(plane, check, level);
        if (element == -1) {
          plane[i] = 1;
          cout << "You have booked a seat at economy class, and you are seated "
                  "at seat number "
               << plane[i] << endl;
          break;
        } else
          cout << "There are no seats available in economy class. Would you "
                  "like a seat at first class?/n(Type 'yes' to continue and "
                  "'no' to exit)"
               << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == "yes") {
          for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            int element = linearSearch(plane, check, level);
          if (element == -1) {
            plane[i] = 1;
            cout << "You have booked a seat at first class, and you are seated "
                    "at seat number "
                 << plane[i] << endl;
            break;
          } else
            cout << "There are no seats available. The next flight leaves in 3 "
                    "hours."
                 << endl;
          break;
        } else
          cout << "There are no seats available. The next flight leaves in 3 "
                  "hours."
               << endl;
        break;

        break;
      }
      break;
    }

    default:
      break;
  }
}

int linearSearch(const int Array[], int key, int sizeofArray) {
  for (int j = 0; j < sizeofArray; j++) {
    if (Array[j] == key)
      return j;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Any help or insight will be appreciated!

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary amount of code. Please provide [mcve]. Focus on the *minimal* part, please. That also applies to your explanation of the problem.

Comment: So you seem to have missed a `{` after else in your code. This would lead to the `cin >>answer` statement being outside else and run always. That might be the issue.

Comment: Why are you looping over 5 seats and looping inside linearSearch?  Why are you not checking whether the seat is sold before booking it?

Comment: @stark Checking whether the seat is sold is the idea, that's what I'm trying to do (but I am obviously failing)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your linearSearch function. It return one for first found element. So if at least one array cell is equal to 1 it will return that everything is booked even if all other cells are free. You should search for free cells, not booked one.